# PHP Ajax JSON Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm having trouble with some Ajax and PHP.

When I try sending a JSON response to an Ajax call, I get the following error:

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 0
```

Using dev tools I see the response contains my Controller may be the cause of the problem.

```
    \Ajax\Controller\SimpleTestController{"result":{"1":"message"}}
```

What is causing this?

Most common Google/SO results have the '<' as the unexpected token because it is due to an error being returned but I think this is different.

JS

```
    $(document).on("change", '#selection', function(e) {

                var value = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {'testselection': value},
                    url: '/test/ajax/simple_test',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processResults: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        console.log(thrownError);
                        console.log(xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });

            });
```

PHP

```
    <?php
    namespace Ajax\Controller;
    use Controller\BasicController;

    class SimpleTestController extends BasicController{
        public function indexAction()
        {
            if(isset($_GET['testselection'])){
                $result = array(1 => "message");
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
            }
        }
    }
```

Console log

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at m.parseJSON (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5)
    at e.parseJSON (jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Pb (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5)
    at x (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5)

    OK
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**-- EDIT --**

Using Chrome dev tools

Response

```
    \Ajax\Controller\SimpleTestController{"result":{"1": "message"}}
```

Preview

```
    \Ajax\Controller\SimpleTestController{"result":{1: "message"}}
      "result":{1: "message"}
        1: "message"
```

Hitting /test/ajax/simple_test just prints the controller namespace

```
    \Ajax\Controller\SimpleTestController
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Sorry people.  Turns out it was echoing my class because a friend of mine modified my code so he could learn/understand how I routed my pages.

Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: What is the raw response in developers console?

Comment: Go to networks tab and send raw response

Comment: Try to print Json Array in PHP file. See what it outputs.

Comment: What do you get when you hit `/test/ajax/simple_test` ?

Comment: Edited with requested info.  Couldn't get the PHP printing of the array to work because it's an ajax call.

Comment: Namespace should be `Ajax\Controller`

Comment: @ĐàoMinhHạt Yes.  I did change that.  Still having issues.

Comment: See the problem is when hitting the page you are not getting the json, or at least it is not formatted well, so your expected json is starting with the anti-slash `\Ajax\Controller\SimpleTestController` ... What technology are you using ? Which framework or CMS ?

Comment: try to go to network tab near console browser  , find /test/ajax/simple_test in list and then see the response.

Comment: @LucaOlivieri That's where I got the response info from in the edit

Comment: @teeyo I'm not using any framework or CMS.  This is just a test project I use to test out UI functions.  At the moment I'm trying to do cascading drop downs.

Comment: Are any of your PHP files echoing out your namespace and class names?

Comment: @WhiteFire, I'm saying this because I just tested your PHP code and it returns the expected "well" formated JSON : `{"result":{"1":"message"}}` So I thought maybe the way you work, the controller name is being printed somehow and it ruins the json result your are sending

Comment: Thanks @teeyo and Nick Duncan.  After your comments I decided to comb through my code for a stray echo and found it.  I let my friend who's just starting to learn PHP have a look at the code.  I didn't realised he had put echoes in my dispatcher to see how it worked and assumed he was using my logging Haha.  Man what a headache.  I've been scratching my head for hours on this.

Comment: You welcome @WhiteFire, say hello to your `echo` fiend =P